# SP13 Prem Search Not finding Documents Created From Template

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, document, library

1. Created Document Library
2. Created Content Type with Document as Parent at the top level.
3. Added custom content type to Doc Library.
4. Created/uploaded word document template (started from SP default template).
5. Library is not using check out or versioning.
6. I am the site collection admin, full control of library, and creator of documents so I don't believe it is a permissions issue.

When a new document is created and uploaded using the template it will not show in the library search box.  If searched for using the site search it will find the .aspx page with a web part displaying the document, but again not the document itself.

If a document is upload that was not created using the template all search functions work as expected (custom content type used in both cases).

I do not have access to central admin.  Any ideas?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you explain #4 what is the "SP default template"? Have you tried recreating the template from scratch in Word? If I were an admin I'd look at the crawl logs for the document to see it the template is corrupt or password protected.

Comment: #4 What I meant was the default document template you get when you click in the ribbon "File-->New Document-->Document".  I have recreated the template from scratch.  I think the issue starts once the template is uploaded as the template for the document library.  Each incremental test with the new template worked until I uploaded it as the default template for the library.  This makes no sense to me, but... more testing to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that when you search for a document within that library that it does not show up.

You might want to check with someone who has access to central admin (especially the search service app) to check how the crawls / content sources for this site have been configured? Only when the site/library has been crawled the file will show up in search results.

Also I assume the library/site is part of a content source and has not been taken out of the crawl - whether within the library itself or the SSA?